# How to use declarative QML objects with QML4.8 cpp based state machine frame work

Tags: qt4, qml, state-machine

We're limited to QT 4.84 and as such seem to be stuck with the c++ based State Machine Framework. Our app requirements are moderate in complexity but our UI is coded in QML. Is it possible to use the C++ State Machine framework with QML?

Comment: Generally speaking it should be possible please describe what you want to do! I would suggest to set a `Q_PROPERTY`and handover the QObject via `QDeclarativeContext::setContextProperty()`.